# Ember.computed.any with sync and async attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
App.Farm = DS.Model.extend
  location: DS.attr 'string'

App.Field = DS.Model.extend
  location: DS.attr 'string'
  farm: DS.belongsTo 'farm', async: true
  markerLocation: Ember.computed.any('location', 'farm.location')
```

Somewhere else:

```
location = field.get('markerLocation')
```

If the field's location value is empty, will **location** equal the farm's location value? If not, what's the way to get this done?

Basically, the question here is this:

If I want to grab the markerLocation value, and I'm not using bindings, how do I do it so it waits for the async value if the sync one is not set? Even inside an observer I am having trouble doing this.

Maybe something like this:

```
markerLocation: ( -> 
  promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise (resolve) =>
    location = @get('customLocation')
    if location
      resolve(location)
    else
      @get('farm').then (farm) ->
        resolve(farm.get('location'))
).property('location', 'farm.location')
```

And then get it by doing something like this:

```
location = field.get('markerLocation').then (location) ->
  # do something with location
```

Trying to make it work this way now, and there's some promise there (no pun).

Comment: Came up with almost the same code as you posted but added an extra property for the template: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pukewo/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

1. Question: Yes
2. Question: Like you did it or like on this jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pukewo/1/edit

Play aroung with line 11 and you'll see the results.

Comment: Yes, but you're using bindings. So I guess I have to use an observer?